# Visual Studio encoding problems

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have problems with files encoding in Visual Studio 2008. While compiling I'm getting such errors:

[image]

When I'm trying to open file where particular error occures, encoding window appears:

[image]

By defualt auto-detect is set. When I change encoding option to UTF-8, everything works. If I open each problematic file in my project using UTF-8 encoding, project starts to compile. The problem is I have too many files and there is ridiculous to open each file and set encoding to UTF-8. Is there any way to make this in a quick way ?

My VS settings are:

[image]

I'm using Windows Server 2008 R2.

**UPDATE:**

For Hans Passant and Noah Richards. Thanks for interaction. I recently changed my operating system so everything is fresh. I've also downloaded fresh solution from source control.

In OS regional settings I've changed system locale to Polish(Poland):

[image]

In VS I've changed international settings to the same as windows:

[image]

The problem is still not solved.

When I open some .cs files using auto-detection for encoding, and then check **Files -> Advanced Save Options...**, some of this .cs files have codepage 1250:

[image]

but internally looks following:

[image]

It is wired, because when I check properties of such particular files in source control, they seems to have UTF-8 encoding set:

[image]

I don't understand this mismatch.

All other files have UTF-8 encoding:

[image]

and opens correctly. I have basically no idea what is going wrong because as far as I know my friend has the same options set as me, and the same project compiles for him correctly. But so far he happily hasn't encountered encoding issues.

Comment: You can't have 'too many files' and not have had this problem before.  What changed?  Did you switch to this machine recently?  Is the system code page changed?  Was this project imported from VS2005?  Change to a gimpy SCCS?  Document your problem better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That uppercase A with circumflex tells me that the file is UTF-8 (if you look with a hex editor you will probably see that the bytes are C2 A0). That is a non-breaking space in UTF-8.

Visual Studio does not detect the encoding because (most likely) there are not enough high-ASCII characters in the file to help with a reliable detection.

Also, there is no BOM (Byte Order Mark). That would help with the detection (this is the "signature" in the "UTF-8 with signature" description).

What you can do: add BOM to all the files that don't have one.
How to add? Make a file with a BOM only (empty file in Notepad, Save As, select UTF-8 as encoding). It will be 3 bytes long (EF BB BF).
You can copy that at the beginning of each file that is missing the BOM:

```
   copy /b/v BOM.txt + YourFile.cs YourFile_Ok.cs
   ren YourFile.cs YourFile_Org.cs
   ren YourFile_Ok.cs YourFile.cs
```

Make sure there is a + between the name of the BOM file and the one of the original file.

Try it on one or two files, and if it works you can create some batch file to do that.
Or a small C# application (since you are a C# programmer), that can detect if the file already has a BOM or not, so that you don't add it twice. Of course, you can do this in almost anything, from Perl to PowerShell to C++ :-)

Comment: Thanks for that, nice solution. Still it seems wired that my friend hasn't faced such issue as we have both the same os, the same source files (from the same sc) and I think the same settings. Nevertheless this trick helps me and is a good tip for future. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Once you've opened the files in UTF-8 mode, can you try changing the Advanced Save Options for the file and saving it (as UTF-8 with signature, if you think these files should be UTF-8)?

The auto-detect encoding detection is best-effort, so it's likely that something in the file is causing it to be detected as something other than UTF-8, such as having only ASCII characters in the first kilobyte of the file, or having a BOM that indicates the file is something other than UTF-8.  Re-saving the file as UTF-8 with signature should (hopefully) correct that.

If it continues happening after that, let me know, and we can try to track down what is causing them to be created/saved like that in the first place.